# Does OpenCV runs on platforms with different int size?

Tags: opencv, cross-compiling

I'm writing a library on top of the OpenCV and I have a question about crossplatformability.

My question is: does OpenCV runs if `int` size is other than 32 bits, but 16, 64 or 128? Because if yes, I'd like to support those platforms, otherwise it would simplify my high level interfaces. I didn't find any information and I'm not this familiar with C++ to solve this conundrum myself by looking on sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *int* type is assumed to be 4-bytes wide:  https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h

- bit shifts and masks; it will definitely broke for 16-bit.
- generic 128-bit SIMD C++ implementation assumes 128-bit register = 4 x int values
- some algorithms use SoftFloat library with assumption int = int32_t (example)
- the type identifier for int matrices is named CV_32S
- ...?

So: answer is "No".

Thanks to @mshabunin